# Partials rendering and variables between calls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project I show last 4 comments on a post and then when someone click on the expand comments link rest of the comments should show. I have following code

```
<%= link_to demo_expand_comments_path(:post_id => post.id, comment_id => comment_id ), remote: true do %> 
   This is the link to expand comment.


<div id="comments_container_<%= post.id %>">
          <%= render :partial => 'community/comments/comment_box_posts', :collection => post.comments.order('id DESC').limit(4).reverse, :as => :comment %>
        </div>
```

Here I am rendering first 4 comments

Now when someone click on expand comments, expand_comments action is called and in expand_comment.js.erb has following code

```
$('#comments_container_<%= @post_id %>').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'community/comments/comment_box_posts', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>');
```

controller action

```
def expand_comments
    @post_id = params[:post_id]
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = post.comments.where('id < ?', params[:comment_id]).order("created_at ASC")
```

## I need the last shown comment_id here

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{}
    end

  end
```

Now what I need help is that when expand comments action is called I want to send the post id and the last comment id I am showing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can change your "expand comment" link as well as you render comments.

In controller:

```
def expand_comments
  ...
  @comment_id = @comments.last.id
```

Then in expand_comment.js.erb:

```
$('#comments_container_<%= @post_id %>').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'community/comments/comment_box_posts', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>');
$('#id_of_link').attr('href', '<%= demo_expand_comments_path(:post_id => @post_id, comment_id => @comment_id ) %>');
```

But it is not way I like.

Don't send comment_id parameter like url parameter. You should send it by ajax request.

Remove comment_id parameter from url, store it like data-attribute:

```
<%= link_to demo_expand_comments_path(:post_id => post.id), data: {comment_id: @comment_id} do %> 
This is the link to expand comment.
...
```

Note that you have to remove "remote: true" from link_to too.

Send ajax request when link clicking:

```
$('#id_of_link').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: $(this).attr('href),
    data: { comment_id: $(this).data('comment_id') },
    dataType: 'script'
  });
  return false;
});
```

And update comment_id attribute when comments rendering:

```
$('#comments_container_<%= @post_id %>').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'community/comments/comment_box_posts', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>');
$('#id_of_link').data('comment_id', '<%= @comment_id %>');
```

Comment: '@comment_id = @comments.last.id'  this will get the last comment id from database but I need the last comment id I already showed or rendered under that post

Comment: You'r right. You have to add correct *limit* and *order* conditions in controller by yourself )